# Button on breadboard will not do anything

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ros

Today I was trying to make a simple circuit to play with some LEDs and buttons. I was following along with a video called [Basic usage of the raspberry pi gpio pins by Engineer man on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6N5pRDOrg4). I was able to get the part of the code working that's just the LED flashing by itself. However, trying to get the button involved and it doesn't do anything. Here is the code:

```py
#This is a node used to control the-------with Raspberry Pi GPIO

#import rospy
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
#from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
#from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy
#from std_msgs.msg import Bool

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

for i in range(5):
    GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(.2)
    GPIO.output(20, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(.2)

led_on=False
def switch(ev=None):
    global led_on
    led_on = not led_on
    GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH if led_on else GPIO.LOW)
    
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING, callback=switch, bouncetime=300)

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this, the light flashes five times then when I try to light it with the button it does nothing. I've check the button itself for continuity through the board so it should be working. Any ideas as to why it isn't?
I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu.

Comment: Just stating the obvious here, but are you sure you've connected the wires to the right pin(s)? Mainly since you are using BCM mode

Comment: Yes everything physically is good. @Vvamp

Comment: try increasing your bouncetime a little - I don't see anything wrong with your code, perhaps the event is firing twice in quick succession?

Comment: Put it to 1000, still nothing :,) @Vvamp

Comment: Your code seems absolutely fine to me. Unless I'm missing something, it has to be a physical issue

Comment: Do you mind adding a picture or pin diagram of your connections?

Comment: Since the code is basically the same as in the video (except pin numbers and timing) where it's shown working, why do you think that the problem is with the code?